# Devices storing volatile memory

Tags: capacitor, digital-logic, flipflop, memory, mips

I've hit a bit of a rut in a question on my homework for my computer architecture class (MIPS architecture):

> what are digital logic devices that can implement 1 bit and 32 bit volatile memory, and what are microarchitecture devices that can implement 1 bit and 32 bit volatile memory?

As I understand it a capacitor and a flip-flop can both hold 1 bit, but I'm not sure about the 32 bit answers.

Comment: An array of 32 flip flops?

Comment: I know this is a typical CS computer arch basics question, but I don't like it: "a capacitor can store 1 bit" is ... not exactly true. It stores *charge*, and that's an analog thing, and you'll need to read it out (e.g. by measuring the voltage across the cap) to get a bit. And here's where things get interesting: For example, in flash memory, data is stored in the charge (of a gate capacitor of a transistor). But: it's not one bit per capacitor; at all! First of all, much, if not even most, of modern flash is multi-level, so that the charge is quantized to give more than a 0/1 decision;

Comment: so, your average modern USB thumb drive has already typically TLC, three bit levels per cell, i.e. 3 bits per cell. But that's also not the whole truth – you really can't use that memory to store a full 3 bits of information. Because the whole analog charge business is so unreliable, you need to add a lot of error correction, even to single-level flash memory, that you often need to do something like "read 2048 bits to get 864 bits", using the magic of channel coding. I know, this is far beyond the scope of your lecture, but "a capacitor stores a bit" is simply wrong – it stores a charge.